# pass a variable into $routeProvider in angular between views? - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Wondering if there's an 'angular specific' way to try and achieve this.
I have a page with some views. When a user clicks an anchor, the views change, simple enough.  What I'm curious is, if when the user clicks, is it possible to store a variable (say the span) then pass it to the `$routeProvider` to load the content a bit more dynamically?

so for anchor tag #name1, when that view is displayed, I can pass "name1" into `nameHolder` as a variable to load some files with same name.

HTML

```
<a href="#name1"><span>name1</span></a>
```

JS

```
var nameHolder = [];
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/' + nameHolder, {
        templateUrl: 'templates/individkcd.html',
        controller: 'individ',
        nameofuser: nameHolder
    }).
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    });
}]);


sampleApp.controller('individ', function($scope, $route) {

    $scope.img =  $route.current.nameHolder;


});
```

Thanks for any info.

**UPDATED:**
Solution at new thread.

[angular js - passing a variable into $routeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416802/angular-js-passing-a-variable-into-routeprovider/28416882#28416882)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the parameter to your [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) template:

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/' + nameHolder, {
        templateUrl: 'templates/individkcd/:nameHolder',
        controller: 'individ'
    }).
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    });
}]);
```

Then in your target controller use [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

```
sampleApp.controller('individ', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.img =  $routeParams.nameHolder;


});
```

From the $routeProvider docs linked above:

> `path` can contain named groups starting with a colon: e.g. :name. All
>   characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches

Comment: Gave this a shot but, still doesnt seem to recognize I passed a variable into the array.  created a jsfiddle.  I have a feeling theres a much easier way to achieve what i want within angular's framework,.  http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/rdko8qqs/1/

Comment: You've missed the most important step: putting the variable name into the templateUrl. See the first code block and quote in my answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/rdko8qqs/5/ closer, if I manually enter "that" as the variable, it works, now just need to find a way to pass it dynamically and update. I feel like i would need to setTimeout upon initiating the controller but Im not sure, or if that's a possibility.  I did try passing the variable name into the template URL but, that was still not working..