# AngularJS - Passing a variable into `$routeProvider`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to figure out an 'Angular specific' way to try and achieve this.
I have a page with some views. When a user clicks an anchor, the views change, which I have working just fine.

What I'm curious is, if when the user clicks, is it possible to store a variable (say the inner html) then pass it to the `$routeProvider` to load the view a bit more dynamically?

So for anchor tag `#name1`, when that view is displayed, I can pass `name1` into `nameHolder` as a variable to load some files with the same name.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="this.html">    
  This Page.
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="that.html">
  That Page.
</script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/this">this</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/that">that</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var nameHolder= [];

var app = angular.module( "myApp", ['ngRoute'] );

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/' + nameHolder, {
        templateUrl: nameHolder + ".html",
        controller: 'individ',
        nameofuser: nameHolder
    }).
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'this.html'
    });
}]);

app.controller('individ', function($scope, $route) {
  $scope.img =  $route.current.nameofuser;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    nameHolder.length = 0;
    var pushThis = $(this).text();
    nameHolder.push(pushThis);
    console.log(nameHolder)
  });
});
```

Thanks for any info.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/rdko8qqs/8/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use function for [`templateUrl`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to dynamically construct url. This function accepts an object of route parameters:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/:nameHolder', {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
            return params.nameHolder + ".html";
        },
        controller: 'individ',
        nameofuser: nameHolder
}).
```

Comment: awesome solution, thank you. Updated working fiddle with your code.  I didn't realize I could pass a function with 'templateUrl'.  http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/rdko8qqs/9/

Comment: Updated reusing the "this.html" tpl. http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/rdko8qqs/11/