# Angular analytics view variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been having trouble tracking some more subtle changes in the UI of apps.

Where should a "state" variable go that can be accessed in the DOM? I've looked at using Angulartics but it's too heavyweight for what I need, which is just one JS object for tracking state.

for example:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ui.router','ct.ui.router.extras.dsr']); 
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/"); 
        $stateProvider
    .state('main',
    url:"/main",
             deepStateRedirect: true,
    views : {
        pane: {
            templateUrl : 'tpl.pane-0.html'
            },
        }
    )
.state('files',
    url: '/files',
             deepStateRedirect: true,
    views : {
        pane : {
            templateUrl : 'tpl.pane-1.html'
            },
        'first@files' : {
            templateUrl : 'tpl1.first.html',
                          deepStateRedirect: true
            },
        'second@files' : {
            templateUrl : 'tpl1.second.html',
                          deepStateRedirect: true
            },  
        },
    )
  });
```

Please advise.

Comment: *what* variable? This question is way too vague for anyone to understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry, I posted it before I was ready for feedback. Please take a look now.

Comment: this answer was confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392960/pass-a-variable-into-routeprovider-in-angular-between-views-angularjs?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have it passed as a route paramater.

The example from ui.router doc.

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    url: "/contacts/:contactId",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function($stateParams) {
      // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
      expect($stateParams).toBe({
        contactId: "42"
      });
    }
  })
```

The full doc page: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

If you want to share the value with other controllers you can store it in a value like this.

```js
angular.module('myApp').value('contactId', '');

$stateProvider
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    url: "/contacts/:contactId",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function($stateParams, contactId) {
      // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
      contactId = $stateParams.contactId;

    }
  })
```

Later other controllers can import contactId as an injectable reference and use it.

Comment: Ok, so this works but the contactID variable will not have scope outside of the controller. But I could just declare contactId outside of the function, and it would be fine.

Comment: for that I would rather make a service to store the value and share it across multiple controllers. :)

Comment: I would rather do that since inlining controllers isn't exactly something you'd want to do on a large scale app. :)

Comment: @Nice-Guy I stand corrected. The value recipe fits a lot better for this situation. That way your state will also be injectible in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.